# What is the meaning of inflection points in the dispersion relation inside the first Brillouin zone?

Tags: condensed-matter

I have a question regarding the $E$ vs $k$ curve in the first Brillouin zone. Why does the curve have an inflection point at some value of $k$ in the curve?
How does it physically support it?

[image: E vs k]

Comment: @user43033: what is the physical problem with an inflection point in the dispersion ?

Comment: Sorry! I mean ,what is the physical significance of inflection point here. Because in a E vs k curve of free particle, you get a parabola and here the curve has inflection point.Why is it so?

Comment: @user43033 This looks like a cosine band (i.e. -cos(ka)), which is what you typically expect in a [tight-binding model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tight_binding) of a 1-dimensional periodic system.